# get yahoo contacts using yahoo contacts api

Tags: php, yahoo, yahoo-api

I am going to use **[`Yahoo Contacts API`](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/)**. It's working **[`in this page`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%20social.contacts%20WHERE%20guid=me)** as a test. But the problem is, I have 90 contacts in my email but this query returns only 10 for me:

```
select * from social.contacts where guid=me
```

Is this because of testing?! if not, how can I get all my contacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

count is the QUERY PARAMETER that you are looking for

If count is not specified, the Contacts API will return 10 contacts. To get the entire list of contacts, use count=max

https://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/contacts-resource.html#contacts_resources-query_params

this is the link to the documentation page that describes it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if some of the contacts in your Yahoo address book were imported from Facebook?

If so, that's definitely your problem.